# How to use a SQLite table's default values?

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking to insert data into a column like so:

```
INSERT INTO Song values (null, 'Truth of a Liar')
```

into a table set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Song (id integer primary key, name varchar(255), count int not null default 0)
```

and I get the following error: `table Song has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied  INSERT INTO Song2 values (null, 'Truth of a Liar')`

I was expecting be able to not put in the last column because I occasionally might have to put in the `count` value. I'm aware that I could explicitly fill the columns like so:

```
INSERT INTO Song(id, name) values (null, 'msdads')
```

but I was hoping for an alternative.

**Is there another way to `INSERT` data into tables, using some default values and some set values?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
INSERT INTO Song values (null, 'Truth of a Liar',0)
```

when you do not want to insert anything for last column. When you want to occasionally insert a value, you can use that value instead of 0.

Comment: Alright, that seems basic enough, just put in the default value in manually like that.